# Validation for email id using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m trying to validate emailid using jquery.When a invalid special character is pressed which is not to be used in email an alert message as to be displayed invalid email id.If it is valid
it can be proceed to  fill other details

Here is the code.

```
   $("#emailid").bind("keypress", function (event) {
    if (event.charCode != 0) {
        var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (!filter.test(emailid)) {
           alert('Please enter a valid email address');
           event.preventDefault();
           return false;
        }
    }
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div>
 <label>Email Id </label>
 <input type="text" name="emailid" id="emailid"  style="width: 300px;border:solid 1px #0096ce;"/>
</div>
```

In this code if we type letters or any characters it displays error message. Please tell me whats wrong with the code

Comment: why not use `onblur` event instead of keypress?

Comment: What is wrong? You call it on every key press of course it is not valid when they start typing!

Comment: every time you press any key your input is being tested using regexp and the default behavior is prevented. So validation should be made when you've typed your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative that i have used to check email with on blur, you can try it:

```
$("#emailid").on("blur", function (event) {
   var str = $(this).val();
   var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

   if (!filter.test(str)) {
      alert('Please enter a valid email address');
      return false;
   }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/0uxrt2rc/)**

Answer (score 1):

**Try this..**

```
<input type="email" class="email"/>

<div id="message"></div>
<script>
$('.email').on('keyup', function(){
    var valid = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/.test(this.value) && this.value.length;
    $('#message').html('It\'s'+ (valid?'':' not') +' valid');
});
</script>
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/o7t8991c/

Answer (score -1):

If you do want to display an alert you can do this:

```
function isvalidEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}


$("#emailid").keyup(function (event) {
  var emailValue = $(this).val();
  console.log(emailValue);
  if(!isvalidEmail(emailValue)){
    alert('Please enter a valid email address');
  }
});
```

JS Fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/w0yoaqs5/

Comment: How is that any different?

Answer (score -1):

Using Jquery with alert to an invalid email, [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mz_arain08/xjmmax8g/)

```
    <h4>
    <br />Email <span>*</span>
    </h4>                       
    <input type="text" id="Email" name="Email" maxLength="50" size="45" />

$("#Email").blur(function() 
{
 var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;  
 var emailaddress = $("#Email").val();
 if(!emailReg.test(emailaddress)) 
 {
        alert('Please enter valid Email address!');  
        return false;
 }
});
```

**OR** Using javascript function [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is probably way. Example (**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ozeyag/19)**):

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

**NOTE:** But keep in mind that one should not rely only upon JavaScript validation. JavaScript can easily be disabled. This should be validated on the server side as well.

Comment: It does not solve the ACTUAL PROBLEM. Question is not how to validate an email.

Comment: Can you guide me so i update my code about whats the actual problem with my code?

Answer (score -2):

You can change `type="text"` to `type="email"' . You don't need use jQuery in this case. :)

Comment: I had tried using type="email" but it was not working in my php form